# FOSUser - Disabling login page for logged user

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I tryed for 3 days to make a redirection in FOSUser to redirect logged people to index if they try to access the login page, but unfortunately it's seems that there are no way to do this.

How can I do this ?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18783526/1119601)

Answer (score 1):

This little extension in the loginAction should do the trick..

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()
if (is_object($user) && $user instanceof UserInterface) {
    return  new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('_your_route'));
}
```

Comment: this cant work because you havent login behind firewal... so your security.context = NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can override FOSUserBundle SecurityController loginAction() method. Inside, check if the user is connected with `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();` and redirect with `$this->redirect` if needed.

Comment: The probleme is that when im logged an i go to login page, i become anononymous !so if i test with is_object($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()) it doesnt work !

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with **default_target_path** in firewall configuration:

```
security:
    firewalls:
    somename:
        form_login:
            default_target_path: /your-desired-path
```

Find the official description in the book: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#form-login-configuration

Comment: this is after login ... not if user is logged