# Restrict users from multiple pages

Tags: php, symfony

I have been told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134774/restrict-or-redirect-logged-in-users-from-login-page) how to restrict logged in users from the login page and I've also been told to make a new question, so here I am.

How can I restrict users from certain pages, either logged in users from more than the login page, or not logged in users from pages like 'my profile' without having to write a check in every controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SESSION["user"]))
{
    header('index.php');
}
```

Will sent user back to index.php

Comment: hmm i think OP is looking for a more robust solution using the symfony framework... i think you may have missed the link to his previous question