# symfony firewall not redirect to correct login form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I my website I have 3 kinds of user: admin, professor and student
I have 3 login form for each user that can login to system . but when a  user is not logged in and try to access his secure area, he redirects to /login path . he must login to correct path for example students must redirect to /student/login.
my sycurity.yml is

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
        ROLE_DEFAULT: ROLE_USER
    providers:
        utab_user_admin_user_bundle:
            id: utab_user_admin_user.user_provider.username
        mportfolio_professor_bundle:
            id: mportfolio_professor.user_provider.username
        mportfolio_student_bundle:
            id: mportfolio_student.user_provider.username       

    firewalls:
        admin_firewall:
            pattern: ^/admin/
            form_login:
                provider: utab_user_admin_user_bundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   /admin/login
                default_target_path: /admin/profile
                always_use_default_target_path: false
            logout:       
                path: /admin/logout
                target: /admin/login
            anonymous:    true
        professor_firewall:
            # Pattern should equal the pattern you configured for the bundle
            pattern: ^/professor/
            form_login:
                provider: mportfolio_professor_bundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                check_path:     /professor/login_check
                failure_path:   /professor/login
                default_target_path: /professor/profile
                always_use_default_target_path: false
            logout:       
                path: /professor/logout
                target: /professor/login
            anonymous:    true
        student_firewall:
            # Pattern should equal the pattern you configured for the bundle
            pattern: ^/student/           
            form_login:
                provider: mportfolio_student_bundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                check_path:     /student/login_check
                failure_path:   /student/login
                default_target_path: /student/profile
                always_use_default_target_path: false
            logout:       
                path: /student/logout
                target: /student/login
            anonymous:    true
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

        - { path: ^/professor/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/professor/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/professor/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/professor/, role: ROLE_DEFAULT }

        - { path: ^/student/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/student/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/student/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/student/, role: ROLE_DEFAULT }
```

I am using FOSUserBundle and RollerworkermultiuserBundle to handle multi user system

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18783381/2484968 I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: If a user is not logged in then he is anonymous. How could you determine which login-form should be called?

Comment: @Djuro Mandinic  my problem is when no user is logged in and when call a page like this `http://localhost:8000/admin/profile`   he redirected to `localhost:8000/login` instead of `localhost:8000/admin/login`

Comment: @ Frankbeen It is my question!! How can I detemine correct form?

Comment: I think you can not determine which form. If you have 3 forms, each person (kinds of user) should be supplied a particular url for the version of form one should use.

Comment: @Frankbeen the pattern in each firewall should determine this.

Comment: No the patterns are used AFTER login.

Comment: You should make only one loginform and after a succesfull login determine the users role and depending of the role you could redirect the user to where you like

Comment: @Frankbeen I cant use role!! each user is in a table. and i cant change database structure

Comment: @Frankbeen is it because the rules from `access_control` from are called before the firewalls?