# Redirection after login based on user role

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FosUserBundle in Symfony 3.4. I want to redirect users based on their roles. For example, if the role is Client, the user will be redirected to the clients page. If the user is an Admin, then the user will be redirected to the admin dashboard page. How can I do this with FosUserBundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect them both to a controller named `indexAction()` and Redirect them in the controller based on the role. Something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/secure-area", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction()
{

    if($this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN'))
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_area'));
    elseif($this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_USER'))
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('client_area'));
    throw new \Exception(AccessDeniedException::class);
}
```

*EDIT:*
You should set the **default_target_path** to the path above

Comment: Yes it does. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783381/fosuserbundle-redirect-from-login-page-after-logged-in

Comment: i have tried your solution i changed the roles attribute of a random user in the fos_user table in my database and tried to login with it but i got "Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem" due to it's role

Comment: In Symfony 4 I had to do this like below:

`if ( in_array( 'ROLE_ADMIN', $this->getUser()->getRoles(), true) ) ...`